# How to parse collan delimited data in liquid template

Tags: azure, liquid, azure-logic-apps

trying to separate collan delimited data

```
{% assign s1= content.root.Data %}


"s2":"{{ s1 | Split:":" }}",

Data = 25:sgt
i want only sgt value 

{% assign s1= content.root.Data %}


"s2":"{{ s1 | Split:":" | "s1[0]"}}",
```

above code is returning 25sgt without collan. Thats fine. but i am trying to fetch after collan value

Answer (score 0):

Using the [Liquid Sandbox](https://jumpseller.com/support/liquid-sandbox/) tool, the following works for me to extract the value `sgt` for `"s1:"sgt"` result:

> {% assign s1 = "25:sgt" | split: ":" %}
>
> "s2": {{ s1[1](https://jumpseller.com/support/liquid-sandbox/) }}

Screenshot:

[image]